# Problem saving text from UITextView into Realm (Swift 5)

Tags: swift, xcode, save, realm

Trying to save the user's textView.text into Realm. Figured if I call my save function into the textFieldDidEndEditing function, it would trigger my Realm database to save it. Function runs ok (prints "Saved Successfully" when I end editing), but when I close out and come back, none of the data is there.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class NoteViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    var textView = UITextView()
    var notes: Results<Notes>?
    let realm = try! Realm()

    var selectedNote: Menu? {
        didSet {
           loadNotes()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var theTextView: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadNotes()

        self.textView.delegate = self

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        saveNote()
    }




    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

     saveNote()
    }



   //MARK: - Data Manipulation

    func loadNotes() {
        notes = realm.objects(Notes.self)

        textView.reloadInputViews()


    }

    func saveNote() {
        if let currentNote = self.selectedNote {
                 do {
                     try self.realm.write {
                         let newNote = Notes()
                         newNote.body = theTextView.text!
                         newNote.dateCreated = Date()
                         currentNote.notes.append(newNote)
                        print("Saved successfully")
                     }
                 } catch {
                     print("Error saving note body, with \(error)")
                 }
             }


    }


}

Realm File: 

class Notes: Object {
    @objc dynamic var body: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var dateCreated: Date?
    var parent = LinkingObjects(fromType: Menu.self, property: "notes")

}

Menu Realm File:

class Menu: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var preview: String = ""

    let notes = List<Notes>()
```

}

```
 '''
```

Comment: I have a couple of questions for you. Is your Menu object already managed by realm? Or does it still need to be saved to realm? Is your NoteViewController for editing and creating a note? Post as much code as you can. At a minimum it would be helpful to see your Menu class definition, what you are loading in the textView, and how you load the textView with text.

Comment: What does *none of the data is there* mean? Did you use Realm Studio and inspect the database to see if it was actually saves? Also, selectedNote appears to be a Menu `var selectedNote: Menu?` is that correct? Where is that var set?

Comment: Thanks y'all. Just added the Menu class to the code above. I did check the realm file in Studio -  it's saving the menu data and the note class' dateCreated just fine, but not the body of the note.

Comment: That tells me that `theTextView.text!` is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a storyboard to create your layout.

Get rid of `var textView = UITextView()` and `textView.reloadInputViews()` then.

Replace `self.textView.delegate = self` with `theTextView.delegate = self` in viewDidLoad().

To check the content of theTextView modify your print statement:

```
print("Saved successfully: \(theTextView.text!)")
```

If there is no text printed right after "Saved successfully: " then check Interface builder for theTextView: verify the outlet of theTextView and that this is actually the UITextView you are using (since your app does print something it looks like it is hooked up somehow because otherwise it would crash in `newNote.body = theTextView.text!`).

I think you also forgot to actually initialise theTextView with notes.body.
Try to modify loadNotes() like this:

```
func loadNotes() {
    notes = realm.objects(Notes.self)

    theTextView.text = notes.body
}
```